# Filter database fields by date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a page that shows user activity, I have built a form where the user can filter this by date.

Here is the form

```
<form action='filter_activity.php' method='get'>
    From: <input type='text' name='from' value='dd/mm/yyyy'>
    To: <input type='text' name='to'  value='dd/mm/yyyy'>
    <input type='submit' value='Filter'>
```

Here is the `filter_activity.php` page:

```
$from=$_GET["from"];
$to=$_GET["to"];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID=$user AND created between $from and $to ");
```

However this shows nothing, can anyone help?

Comment: 1. You are wide open to SQL injections 2. You have to encapsulate strings in quotes in your query 3. Your date format is invalid

Comment: How is the date stored in your database? What format?

Comment: @Gavin - It is stored like `2013-11-14 19:45:00` (Timestamp)

Comment: 02/20/1971 will be greater than 01/01/2013.  You need YYYY-MM-DD which is most likely the format in the db if the column is of date/time type.  I would use a date picker and force YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: You need to convert UK date to Unix date format.

Comment: @gavin How do i do this?

Comment: Look at @Glavić's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted dates are in invalid format for DB use. You need to convert them before use in DB.

```php
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['from']);
$to   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['to']);

$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM member 
    WHERE personID = $user AND created BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
";
$sql = sprintf($sql, $from->format('Y-m-d'), $to->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Plus, you should check if `$_GET` keys exists and after that, check if `$from` and `$to` are DateTime object, and not `false`.

Comment: Thanks, However it doesn't seem to be resulting anything?

Comment: @user2149630: can you show me what does `$sql` variable look like after `sprintf()` function?

Comment: Could you possibly open a conversation?

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast it to date like:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID=$user AND created BETWEEN DATE('$from') AND DATE('$to')") or die(mysql_error());
```

from the site :

For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly 
convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two 
DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. 
If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, 
cast the string to a DATE.

Comment: MySQL `DATE()` function doesn't convert format, it just extract date part from datetime format. Try to run `SELECT DATE('10/11/2013')` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the correct date format to the DB:

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_GET["from"])));
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_GET["to"])));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID=$user AND created BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
```

*Really think about changing the format in your form*. I would use a date picker, either year/month/day dropdowns or javascript.

Also, read the other comments about quoting, SQL injection, etc.  And get off of mysql_* functions.

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy` is invalid format for PHP, so `strtotime()` will fail, when day will be bigger than 12. That is because PHP assumes that given date is American date format `mm/dd/yyyy`. **[Try it out](https://eval.in/68217)**.

Comment: Ahh yes, I didn't pay attention to that, just that it was not the DB format.  If - is used it will work.  Edited.  `strtotime()` likes `m/d/Y` and `d-m-Y`.