# Filter by time and date

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

I am trying to filter results from a MySQL DB but not having much luck.

The user will complete a form, with a from and to date (EG FROM 01/11/2013 TO 14/11/2013)

Here is my code to filter the results:

```
$dbserver = "localhost";
$dbname = "nameofDB";
$dbusername = "username";
$dbpassword = "password";

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE personID = 84587749 AND DATE(time) BETWEEN ? AND ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){

    /*
    Binds variables to prepared statement


    i    corresponding variable has type integer
    d    corresponding variable has type double
    s    corresponding variable has type string
    b    corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
    */

   $to = $_POST['to'];
   $from = $_POST['from'];

   $stmt->bind_param('ss', $from, $to);


   /* execute query */
   $stmt->execute();

   /* Get the result */
   $result = $stmt->get_result();

   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Configure this how you want to print out each row.
        echo 'Details: '.$row['details'].'<br>';
        echo 'Time: '.$row['time'].'<br>';
        echo 'Balance: '.$row['balance'].'<br>';
        echo '<br><br>';
   }

   /* free results */
   $stmt->free_result();

   /* close statement */
   $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

This is showing no results, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the values you're getting from $_POST? Unless they correspond exactly to a mysql standard date/time string, e.g.

```
 yyyy-mm-dd
```

Then you cannot directly stuff those $_POSt values into your query without appropriate translation logic.

e.g.

```
... WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN 'Jan 31' and 'Feb 28'
```

is not a valid comparison, but

```
... WHERE DATE(TIME) BETWEEN '2013-01-31' and '2013-02-28'
```

**IS** valid.

Comment: @user2149630: why are you asking the same question over and over again? You already know how to convert date formats. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19987026/67332 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19988027/67332

Comment: @Glavić - because no one seems to know how to get this to work from a form, is it not possible?

Comment: doesn't matter what your form submits. if you're passing those from-a-form-dates into  mysql, you have to conform to mysql's standards for date/time strings.